# Java List<Integer> conversion to List<BigInteger> issue?

Tags: java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
   list.add(12);
   list.add(13);

   // can not cast
   List<BigInteger> coverList = (List<BigInteger>)list;
}
```

The above code fails to compile

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
   list.add(12);
   list.add(13);

   Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(1);
   map.put("list", list);
   List<BigInteger> coverList = (List<BigInteger>) map.get("list");

   System.out.println(coverList.size());
}
```

The above code compiles successfully and runs successfully

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cast a `List<Integer>` to a `List<BigInteger>`. Instead, you have to map each `Integer` to a `BigInteger` in a new `List`. The easiest way, in Java 8+, is to use a `stream()` and the `map` function. Like,

```
List<BigInteger> coverList = list.stream()
        .map(i -> BigInteger.valueOf(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As for why the second example works, [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) causes all generic types to be `Object` at runtime. Be aware, that it also adds a bridge method; so your current code will fail at runtime (with a `ClassCastException`) once you access a value in the `List` **as** a `BigInteger`. This was the source of many bugs in the days before Java had generics.

For example,

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
list.add(12);
list.add(13);

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(1);
map.put("list", list);
List<BigInteger> coverList = (List<BigInteger>) map.get("list");
List<BigInteger> coverList2 = list.stream()
        .map(i -> BigInteger.valueOf(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(coverList.get(0));
BigInteger bi = coverList.get(0);
System.out.println(bi);
```

Outputs

```
12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.math.BigInteger (java.lang.Integer and java.math.BigInteger are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```